# MainWindow's Frame.Content disappears when passed as reference parameter to another Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement a pop-out logic for a module that I'm currently working on in WPF. Currently, i was able to do as much as be able to pop out the `Page` to a `PopoutWindow` and pass the current instance of it. However, i am not able to re-dock the said `Page` back to `MainWindow` even when `MainWindow.Frame.Content` is explicitly specified. The `Page` simply does not load after `PopoutWindow` is shown with `.Show();`

I currently have 3 `.xaml` files in the project:

`Page1.xaml` - The module that i made on a Page Control that i wish to have a pop-out to window functionality implemented.
`MainWindow.xaml` - The application's main Window Control with a `Frame` control in it with `Page1.xaml` as its `Source`
`PopoutWindow.xaml` - A separate Window Control that also has a `Frame` control in it with the sole purpose of acting as the Window Host for popped out `Page` from `MainWindow`

On `PopoutWindow.xaml.cs`, i made another constructor where i can pass the `.Content` property of a `Frame` control currently docked in `MainWindow`:

```
public PopoutWindow(ref Page frameSource, string title)
{
     InitializeComponent();

     // sourceFrame is the 'Name' of the Frame control defined in PopoutWindow.xaml
     sourceFrame.Content = frameSource;
     Title = title;
}
```

On `PopoutWindow.xaml` however, has nothing really in it as its just mean to hold the undocked `Page` from `MainWindow`:

```
<Window x:Class="PopoutTest.PopoutWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PopoutTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PopoutWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Name="sourceFrame" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Page1` is an example i made that will act as the "module" that can be popped in or out of the `MainWindow`. The idea is the current instance of `Page1` will be passed on to `PopoutWindow` and returned to `MainWindow` when the popout window is closed.

`.xaml`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!"
                   FontSize="30"
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   Name="helloWorldTextBlock" />

        <Button Content="Click Me"
                Name="clickMeButton"
                Click="clickMeButton_Click"
                Width="100"
                Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

`.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
     private int _counter;


     public Page1()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }


     private void clickMeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          helloWorldTextBlock.Text = $"Click Count: {++_counter}";
     }
}
```

`MainWindow`, just like `PopoutWindow` doesn't have much in it, but a `Frame` to load and host the `Page, a` Button`to trigger the`pop-in`, the logic for this` Button`, and a` pop-out`method, and a`TextBlock`that notes that the`Page`is docked and can be clicked to close the`PopoutWindow`and show the`Page to in the `MainWindow` once again.

`.xaml`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Image Source="\image.png"
           Width="25"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
           Panel.ZIndex="1"
           Margin="5"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Window Undocked. Click to redock."
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Name="dockLabel"
               Visibility="Hidden"
               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="dockLabel_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    
    <Frame Source="Page1.xaml"
           Name="windowFrame"
           Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
           Panel.ZIndex="0" />
</Grid>
```

`xaml.cs`:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
      private PopoutWindow popOut;
      private Page popOutSource;


      public MainWindow()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
      }


      private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
           popOutSource = (Page)windowFrame.Content;

           popOut = new PopoutWindow(ref popOutSource, "Page1");
           popOut.ShowDialog();

           windowFrame.Content = popOutSource;

           windowFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
           dockLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      }

      private void dockLabel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
           popOut.Close();

           windowFrame.Content = popOut.sourceFrame.Content;
           windowFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
           dockLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
      }
 }
```

I'm currently stuck in trying to get the undocked `Page` currently in `PopupWindow` to load back on `MainWindow`'s `Frame` control. The `Frame` control immediately loses its content as soon as the `PopupWindow` is shown.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: So you close your popup window ? Are you sure the content isn't disposed already ?  move the popOut.Close(); at the end of the method and see what happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the content of the `windowFrame` by setting the property to `null` before you call `ShowDialog()`. You can then set it back to `popOutSource` once the popout window has been closed and the `ShowDialog` method has returned:

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    popOutSource = (Page)windowFrame.Content;
    windowFrame.Content = null; //<--

    popOut = new PopoutWindow(ref popOutSource, "Page1");
    popOut.ShowDialog();

    windowFrame.Content = popOutSource;

    windowFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    dockLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: that actually worked! Can you explain to me a bit why not setting `.Content = null;` produces the error? i assumed it should because i passed a reference to it and not another instance.